# Range of $\frac x{x^2-4}$

Tags: functions

I am having a hard time determining the range of the function
$$\frac x{x^2-4}$$
if anyone could help me with how to do it and on how to tackle similar questions I would be really pleased

Comment: If you're completely lost, start by drawing a picture

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}\frac{x}{x^2-4}=?$

Comment: Try $$x=2\tan y$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $y = \dfrac{x}{x^2-4}\implies yx^2-x-4y=0$ . The equation with $x \neq \pm 2$ must have at least a real root which means $\triangle = b^2-4ac \ge 0\implies (-1)^2-4(y)(-4y) \ge 0\implies 1+16y^2 \ge0$. This means the range is $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

It has vertical asymptotes at $x=\pm 2,$ and is $0$ at $x=0,$ so range is all reals (using intermediate value theorem).

Note for this conclusion just from the facts used, one needs that at least one of the asymptotes is 2-sided (goes to both $\infty,-\infty$ for $x$ near the asymptote location). Here both are. Also need continuity.

--Also need that function is odd, pointed out by H. Makholm.

Comment: Note that $\frac{x^2-4}{x^4-4}+1$ has the same properties you quote, but _its_ range is not all reals. You need additionally to use that the function is odd.

Comment: Thanks, @HenningMakholm -- will note that.